# How to serve a bootstrap template in sails 0.9?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sails.js

I wanted to know how to serve a bootstrap template through newer sails version . Should I update the links of JS to something else . I tried moving js and images in asset folder but javascript didn't work . The sails documentation is very poor on this topic . Can anyone tell a easy way to integrate it . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sails 0.9.x has moved to use Grunt for handling assets. This allows you to do many different kinds of pre-compilation and asset handling. By default, automatic asset injection into your views and layouts is not available.

We have added a flag you can include when generating a new sails project that will create a folder within your assets folder and automatically inject any files into you index.html or layout file. This should only be used for development.

`sails new <project name> --linker`

Now you will have a folder titled `linker` under your assets folder that you can place files in to have them automatically linked. It will also add some tags to your `index.html` file and your layout file to know where to inject the various JS, CSS and templates.

You can read more here: [Sails Wiki - Assets](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/assets.md)

If you are working with a project that has already been created you can manually create the following file structure:

```
assets/
  linker/
    js/
    styles/
    templates/
```

You will also need to add the following tags to your view:

```html
<!--SCRIPTS-->
All .js files in assets/linker/js will be included here
In production mode, they will all be concatenated and minified
<!--SCRIPTS END-->

<!--STYLES-->
All .css files in assets/linker/styles (including automatically compile ones from LESS) will be included here
In production mode, they will all be concatenated and minified
<!--STYLES END-->

<!--TEMPLATES-->
All *.html files will be compiled as JST templates and included here.
<!--TEMPLATES END-->
```

So to use bootstrap and have the files automatically added to your page you will place the bootstrap.js files into `assets/linker/js` and the bootstrap.css file into `assets/linker/css`.

In production you will want to edit the gruntfile to compile all of your css and js into single files and manually link them in your view/layout/index.html.

Comment: So if there are multiple html files present in templates folder , they all will be crunched together in the<!--TEMPLATES-->
All *.html files will be compiled as JST templates and included here.
<!--TEMPLATES END--> ??? Can you show an example to selectively render a particular html for a url. Sorry but I am really new with grunt .Thanks in advance

Comment: So the templates are for single page web apps. They will be precompiled into JST templates that you can use in your front-end code.

If you want to render views server-side and have them served for a particular route you will want to use the views folder. Here you can use EJS, Jade or any other view logic you would like.

Look at:[Sails View Docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views) for more info on views.

Comment: Why use the linker for development only?

Comment: To the reader please note this is not how to do things in v0.10 [**SAILS v.10 doesn't use linker anymore**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22060890/1795429)

Answer (score 8):

There are an issue with glyphicon. The destination of css file minified is /.temp/public/min/production.css and fonts must be in /.temp/public/fonts/. Then you have to copy fonts folder from assets/linker/fonts/ to /.temp/public/fonts/.

You have to add this in the Gruntfile inside copy.dev.files array:

```
{
    expand: true,
    cwd: './assets/linker/fonts',
    src: ['**/*'],
    dest: '.tmp/public/fonts'
}
```

Or in a more general way:

```
{
    expand: true,
    cwd: './assets',
    src: ['**/fonts/*'],
    dest: '.tmp/public/fonts',
    flatten: true
}
```

It will search for all folders called `fonts` under `assets`. Use `flatten` to avoid subfolders.

Cheers,