# Sails JS: What is template in layout.ejs?

Tags: sails.js

I am using linker in Sails JS.
How to use  ? And What is this?
Is this HTML Template or Javascript Template?
How can I use this?

I tried put a html file in my assets directory.
But I can't understand how to use .jst file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered over here: [How to serve a bootstrap template in sails 0.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929307/how-to-serve-a-bootstrap-template-in-sails-0-9)

Another good resource is [Irl Nathan's excellent video tutorials](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/20/building-a-sails-application-ep1-installing-sails-and-create-initial-project/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.