# Sails not generating linker

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to use associations with Sails.js 0.10, I generated my app with:

```
sails new name --template jade --linker
```

Application is running fine, but I don't see any `assets/linker` folder as I did in version 0.9., are all files minified by default in 0.10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SailsJS v0.10 create new project --linker not working Gruntfile.js not used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042260/sailsjs-v0-10-create-new-project-linker-not-working-gruntfile-js-not-used)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 0.10 you don't need the "linker" folder, it will just compile and link everything in assets/js, assets/styles and assets/templates.

You can check the grunt files (in "tasks" root folder) to figure what's actually done there :).

Comment: hmm, I did not find anything there, or anything I could understand, where could I learn about that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that part of the doc hasn't been updated (beta.sailsjs.org), but you can check out this file, where it says what it is being done in the tasks/config/sails-linker.js file: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-frontend/blob/master/templates/tasks/config/sails-linker.js

Comment: These are grunt tasks, so you may want to check grunt's documentation to fully understand hoy it works. Basically, hoy it is structured, the tasks folder contains two folders: config, which is the folder for the "atomic" tasks, and register, which defines the high level tasks, that end up calling the config ones. compileAssets.js (in the register folder) is the one that calls all the sails-linker:*