# preparing assets for Deploying - Sails v0.10

Tags: deployment, linker, sails.js, production-environment

The documentation of sails (http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Deployment) says:
"Configure the 'production' environment so that all of your css/js gets bundled up, and the internal servers are switched into the appropriate environment (requires linker)"

I thought the linker folder is not used anymore in sails v0.10.([sails.js v0.10 create new project --linker not working Gruntfile.js not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042260/sailsjs-v0-10-create-new-project-linker-not-working-gruntfile-js-not-used/22060890#22060890)):
"Sails v0.10 no longer uses the linker folder--it was just causing confusion."

1. If these two quotes are not a paradoxon I would love to hear why.
2. Can somebody explain that step of deployment above ("Configure the 'production' environment..requires linker")?

Answer (score 0):

When I was deploying our Sails JS application, all I had to do was to set the environment variable NODE_ENV as "production":

```
export NODE_ENV="production"
```

I was using `forever` for keeping the server up, using the command:

```
forever start app.js --prod
```

The server then starts in production environment. Before starting, it automatically bundles up CSS and JS files into `production.css` and `production.js` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Answers not really the questions. But I know now how easy it could be :) Because my app looks different in production and the documentation ("Configure the 'production' environment so that all of your css/js gets bundled up, and the internal servers are switched into the appropriate environment (requires linker)") is pretty thin.

Comment: That's true. The best thing we can do is to help to improve the documentation.