# integrate Twitter bootstrap with sails js v0.10

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sails.js

I am new to sails and bootstrap. I need to integrate bootstrap in an existing sails v0.10 project. Please tell me the steps i should take to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929307/how-to-serve-a-bootstrap-template-in-sails-0-9

Answer (score 8):

you can , add with following step below :

- put the bootstrap css library to folder assets/style/bootstrap
- put the bootstrap javascript library to folder assets/js/bootstrap
- put the jquery  to folder assets/js/dependencies/

add jquery dependecies in task/pipeline.js , because bootstrap required jquery.js like code below :

```
// Client-side javascript files to inject in order
// (uses Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions)
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Load sails.io before everything else
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  // load jquery before bootstrap
  'js/dependencies/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',

  // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/**/*.js'
];
```

And then when you run sails with command sails lift, automatic grunt task running and make your the dependencies configuration implement in your layout like this

```
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Jquery will be load before bootstrap .

Hopefully can help you