# How do I serve images/fonts in Sails 0.11?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, sails.js

I'm trying to serve fonts and images in Sails.js which seems like a simple thing to do but I can't find any examples/documentation on how to actually do it.

I've configured my build tasks to put the fonts in the .tmp/public/fonts folder as expected, however I don't know how to actually get sails lift to serve them.

I came across this article: [How to serve a bootstrap template in sails 0.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929307/how-to-serve-a-bootstrap-template-in-sails-0-9), however I believe the way to do this is different for Sails 0.11.

Any suggestions?